# How to get a Multilist with Search field to not display referenced items' version and language?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

We are using Sitecore 7.2 to build a new application, and making extensive use of the new Multilist with Search field. We would like to be able to turn off display of the listed items' versions and languages in the list fields. How do we do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sitecore 8 and above versions left part of multi-list field is filled by Ajax response from javascript file.

Below line needs to be modified your requirements, which is in

> websiteRoot/sitecore/shell/Controls/BucketList/BucketList.js

```
multilist.options[multilist.options.length] = new Option((item.DisplayName || item.Name) + ' (' + item.TemplateName + (item.Bucket && (' - ' + item.Bucket)) + ')', item.ItemId);
```

For just item name or display name to be display do something like below:

```
multilist.options[multilist.options.length] = new Option((item.DisplayName || item.Name), item.ItemId);
```

Make sure you clear your browser cache after changing the .js file.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do that by creating new field type which inherits '`Sitecore.Buckets.FieldTypes.BucketList`' class.

Then overwrite 'OutputString' method with the following:

```cs
public override string OutputString(Item item4)
{
      Item parentBucketItemOrParent = item4.GetParentBucketItemOrParent();
      string str = (parentBucketItemOrParent != null) ? ("- " + parentBucketItemOrParent.get_Name()) : string.Empty;
      return string.Format("{0} ({1})", new object[] { item4.DisplayName, item4.TemplateName });
}
```

Now you will need to add this field type to Sitecore, go to 'Core' database, and duplicate this item:

/sitecore/system/Field types/List Types/Multilist with Search

In the new item, Clear 'Control' field, and fill '**Assembly**' with your asembly name and 'Class' with your [**Namespace.Classname**]

Hope this will help

**EDIT**

You might need to override this function too, as this generate the JS function that parse the AJAX call when you try to search for a keyword:

```cs
    public override string JavaScriptOutputString(string clientId)
    {
        string[] strArrays = new string[] { "responseParsed", clientId, ".items[i].Name + ' (' + responseParsed", clientId, ".items[i].TemplateName + ')'" };
        return string.Concat(strArrays);
    }
```

Comment: In version 8 this works for the right part of the Multilist with search but not for the left part where search hits are displayed. Do you know how to fix this too?

Comment: @ErikMelkersson I have updated my answer, Have not tested this yet, but i think it should do the trick.

Comment: Thats what I thought too but it actually never gets called according to my log.  I actually tested overriding JavaScriptOutputString before I made my comment (I should have written that...)

Comment: The overloaded methods only gets called on initialization and not after that, i.e. when searching. Could the base class be registered somewhere as actions or something. (just speculating...)

Comment: Actually this method (JavaScriptOutputString) is one of the methods responsible of generating Java script code that handles (OnKeyDown, OnKeyUp) events for multilist filed, Try to open CE on item that has multilist with search and search for this method "applyMultilistFilterFIELD" in Scripts using Fire Bug for example

Comment: Doh! My second comment was weird, yes. But the fact remain that the JavaScriptOutputString method is never called, so It will not generate any javascript. (At least when using "Multilist with search", in sitecore 8.0 rev. 150427)

Comment: The left hand side of the Multilist with Search is controlled by the SuccessHandler function in the BucketList.js (/sitecore/shell/Controls/BucketList). It's hardcoded to use item.Name. I just filed #442147 and asked to at least do item.DisplayName || item.Name but ideally allow it to be customized

Comment: @PavelVeller , did you get an answer ?